# How to do following sql operation using Table.select() method in python sqlobject?

Tags: python, sql, sqlobject

Sql Operation:

```
    SELECT *,
        CASE
            WHEN quota_unit = 'MB' THEN quota*1024
            ELSE quota
        END AS data_usage
    FROM mapping
    ORDER BY data_usage;
```

I tried like this,

```
query = mapping.select('CASE WHEN mapping.quota_unit = 'MB' THEN 1024 * mapping.quota ELSE mapping.quota END AS data_usage)
query.orderBy(data_usage)
res = list(query)
```

but select method taking that value in braces for Where clause and resultant query becomes

```
SELECT * FROM mapping WHERE 'CASE WHEN mapping.quota_unit = MB THEN 1024 * mapping.quota ELSE mapping.quota END AS data_usage'
```

which is not expected. Can you please me here ?

Answer (score 0):

Not every possible SQL query could be mapping back to SQLObject expressions. Sometimes you need to go down to [`SQLBuilder`](http://sqlobject.org/SQLBuilder.html) or even raw queries:

```
results = connection.queryAll(string)
```